# Restart network on RHEL8/CentOs8 thru ssh using nmcli with testing that the operation has finished

Tags: rhel, networkmanager, ipv6

Thru ssh I'm updating the network configuration and then I want to restart the network.

```
systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

doesn't work very well with ipv6 static changes.

So I tried:

```
nmcli connection reload && nmcli networking off && nmcli networking on
```

The above doesn't work as expected but using also `-w` to set a timeout works most of the time.

I'm looking for a more reliable option like do a sort of a test in the command and if is not ok, to retry the commands for a number of times.

Everything needs to be done in one step, because when network is going down, the ssh connection will be lost. A probe will check later with the new configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating the network configuration, you need to use the following command:

```
nmcli connection reload
```

`nmcli manpages`:

```
   reload
       Reload all connection files from disk. NetworkManager does not monitor changes to connection files by default. So you need to use
       this command in order to tell NetworkManager to re-read the connection profiles from disk when a change was made to them.
       However, the auto-loading feature can be enabled and then NetworkManager will reload connection files any time they change
       (monitor-connection-files=true in NetworkManager.conf(5)).
```

Comment: I tried also with reload and is not working on slow network. The problem is that nmcli always returns 0 if it finishes or not, and I need a way to know that the network manager finished the operations and not rely on timeout.